# Usar findViewById em todos escopos ou usar uma variável?

Tags: android, xamarin, desempenho

Qual das estratégias é mais recomendada para uma boa performance de uma aplicação? Usar o `findViewById` sempre que formos usar algum elemento da `View` ou fazê-lo apenas uma vez atribuindo à uma variável?

exemplo em `Xamarin.Android`:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity 
{

  private EditText _CampoNome;

  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
     ...

     _CampoNome = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtCampoNome);
     _CampoNome.Text = "ola mundo";

     EscreverNome(); 
  }

  private void EscreverNome()
  {
      Console.WriteLine(_CampoNome.Text);
  } 
}
```

ou

```
public class MainActivity : Activity 
{
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
     ...

     FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtCampoNome).Text = "ola mundo";

     EscreverNome(); 
  }

  private void EscreverNome()
  {
      Console.WriteLine(FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtCampoNome).Text);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Eu particularmente se vou usar em varias situações e repetidas vezes prefiro criar uma variável, para evitar processamento e reduzir o alocamento de memória, instancio de uma vez logo em vez de instanciar umas 500 vezes

Answer (score 1):

As operações realizadas pelo método `findViewById` podem ser consideradas custosas, mas não costumam afetar o desempenho significativamente fora de listas ou loops. É recomendável que você utilize sempre que possível o padrão `ViewHolder` em listas, assim a reciclagem das views melhora bastante a performance do app.

Como o Gabriel comentou, é mais eficiente que você salve a referência da View em uma variável caso pretenda utiliza-la em diferentes momentos do ciclo de vida.

No caso de layouts com muitos subníveis, você pode economizar algum processamento ao chamar o método `findViewById` em um nível menor da árvore de layout.

Sugiro a leitura desta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26118335/3237900) (em inglês) sobre o mesmo tema.